# How do I get this result usin oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

First, with one collateral, you can borrow money many times from bank. It means that one collateral_num have many loan_num.

Second, you can serve many collaterals to one loan. It means that one loan_num have many collateral_num.

There is a table like this named LOAN.

```
collateral_num | loan_num
-------------------------
 C1            |  A5
 C2            |  A5
 C2            |  A1
 C3            |  A1
 C3            |  A3
 C6            |  A7
 C7            |  A7
```

I want to get minimum collateral_num from LOAN like this table below.
I will explain minium clooateral_num.
There are two group in the first table. One of them is from first row to fifth row. Then, we can find some relationship like  C1→a5→c2→a1→c3→a3 in the first group.
And we discard the nodes including 'a'.
As a result c1 will be minimum collatral num  in c1  c2  c3.(because c1 has the least number.)

In the second group (c6→a7→c7)minimum collatral num will be c6.

```
collateral_num | minimum_collateral_num | loan_num
--------------------------------------------------
 C1            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A5
 C2            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A1
 C3            |   C1                   |    A3
 C6            |   C6                   |    A7
 C7            |   C6                   |    A7
```

How do I make SQL query to make the result I've told. Any comment will be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: `minimum_collateral_num ` is in which table? give your full table structure

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Your edit is
 better, you have hierarchical relationships? Are you basing the "start" of your hierarchy on the "minimum" collateral number in the group? Minimum being defined as the lowest number?

Comment: @HyunJongYui . . . 11gR2 or 11g.  The difference is that 11gR2 supports recursive CTEs which can be use to solve the problem.  Otherwise, I would solve this with repeated updates to a table.

Comment: Yes, It is kind of hierarchical relationship and i doesnt matter where we start. Minimum is defined as the lowest number. @ben

Comment: Are you open to solutions outside of straight SQL, or does this have to be SQL-only?

Comment: It has to be SQL_only

Answer (score 0):

When I have been faced with this problem, I have done the work using repeated updates.  This starts by creating a table with three columns, the collateral id, the load id, and a group id.  Then, it repeatedly sets the collateral to the lowest loan id where the collateral or load ids are the same:

```
create table clgrp as
    select collateral_id, loan_id,
           min(load_id) over (partition by collateral_id) as grp
    from loans;
```

Then repeatedly do this update:

```
update clgrp
    set grp = least((select min(grp)
                     from clgrp join
                          loans
                          on clgrp.collateral_id = loans.collateral_id
                    ),
                    (select min(grp)
                     from clgrp join
                          loans
                          on clgrp.load_id = loans.loan
                    )
                   );
```

Then repeat this process until no rows change.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. But the result wans't what I expected. grp should be c1,c1,c1,c1,c1, c6, c6 but all of grps are 'c1'. Would you teach me what I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant piece of SQL ever but it does produce the correct results.

There are several sub-queries; using the sub-query factoring syntax we can pipe them together  so that the result set of one serves as the input for subsequent queries.

`CTE0` just queries the base table, so we only do that once.

`CTE1` identifies all the collaterals which are linked through loans.

`CTE2` filters the set of minimum collateral numbers.

`CTE3` uses Oracle's hierarchical query syntax to set the minimum (root) collateral number.

`CTE_FIN` (the last one!) uses an analytic LAG() to fill in the null roots.

Having done all that we join the last sub-query with the first, to get the loans - and teh leaf node collaterals.  The UNION is necessary to pick up those instances where one collateral is held against one and only one loan (I added that as [a case in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7eb8f/1)).

```
with cte0 as ( select collateral_num, loan_num from loan )
      , cte1 as (
              select c1.collateral_num as cp
                     , c2.collateral_num as cc
                     , c1.loan_num
               from cte0 c1
                   join cte0 c2
                       on c1.loan_num = c2.loan_num
               where c1.collateral_num < c2.collateral_num )
   , cte2 as ( select cp from cte1
               minus
               select cc from cte1 )
    , cte3 as ( select cte1.cp
                     , cte1.cc
                     , case when cte1.cp = cte2.cp then cte2.cp end as rt
             from cte1
                  left join cte2
                   on cte1.cp = cte2.cp )
    , cte_fin as (
        select cte3.cp
               , cte3.cc
               , nvl(lag(cte3.rt) over (ORDER BY cte3.cp ), cte3.rt) as rt
        from cte3
        connect by prior cte3.cc = cte3.cp
        start with cte3.rt is not null )
select cte0.collateral_num
       , cte0.loan_num
       , cte_fin.rt as min_collateral_num
from cte_fin
     cross join cte0
where cte0.collateral_num = cte_fin.cp
or cte0.collateral_num = cte_fin.cc
union
select cte0.collateral_num
       , cte0.loan_num
       , cte0.collateral_num
from  cte0
where cte0.collateral_num not in (select cp from cte1)
and   cte0.collateral_num not in (select cc from cte1)
order by 3 , 1
/
```

As the Fiddle shows, this query works for the provided sample data.  I offer no guarantees about how it works in real life, with a real data set. I think it would be quite easy to come up with chains of loans and collaterals which break this code.  Doing so is left as an exercise for the reader :)